# I am confused on what this error message says on my code igniter website

Tags: codeigniter

```
Warning: Unknown: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/mk6g6obzufkw/mywebsite.com/index.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (G:/PleskVhosts//autismfights.com\;C:\Windows\Temp\) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in Unknown on line 0

Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required '/home/mk6g6obzufkw/mywebsite.com/index.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php56/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php56/usr/share/php') in Unknown on line 0
```

I did check index.php but I don't see any problem in that. How can I get more detail about error. I am not expert in code igniter but yes I am beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused due to Server Settings.

```
1. Open your cPanel
2. Navigate to PHP Settings
3. Search for Common Settings
4. Check for `open_basedir`
5. Set value as `none`
6. Save the settings
```

Answer (score 1):

The PHP script is trying to access the folder for which access is not allowed. This restriction is limited by the PHP open_basedir variable for each virtual host separately. By default, open_basedir is set to allow access for PHP files to the tmp and HTTP public directories.

So, you have either upload to the wrong folder on the server, set some php.ini value wrong, the host provider has not set up the virtual host correctly, or you have asked CodeIgniter to find a file in somewhere it doesn't have permission read/write/execute.